# Bootstrap 3.0 doesnt work on MasterPage

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap website that i'm creating and it works as a standalone page. ( I can copy the code to an .aspx page[minus placeholders] and it works as expected) however it will not work with a masterpage, i can see it but navbar doesnt "toggle" as expected and the TEXT starts behind the navbar. I have created 2 links, one is a regular page and the other is the masterpage.

MasterPage --http://virtual.aissf.net/test/

Regular --  http://virtual.aissf.net/docs/

MASTERPAGE FILE

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="SiteMaster.master.vb" Inherits="SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/customer.css" rel="stylesheet" />   
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
          <!-- Sidebar -->
<!-- #Include File="Sidebar.html"-->

      <!-- Page content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <!-- Keep all page content within the page-content inset div! -->
        <div class="page-content inset">
            <div class="col-md-10 banner">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="Main" runat="server">

                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 RightLink banner">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="Side" runat="server">

                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</form>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("active");
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just test your link and it works. Could you give me more details please

Comment: If you click on the menu glyph on the [test](http://virtual.aissf.net/test/) it doesnt go out like it does on the doc, have tried it on chrome, IE and firefox.  but as a standalone [Docs](http://virtual.aissf.net/docs/) it works as expected.

Comment: I see this error on your console: downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2): status=2147746065 source: http://virtual.aissf.net/test/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff

Comment: could you please place the script just before the body tag close?

Comment: @naveen not sure what you're asking. Also Vel got the toggle to work and i did get the text to move over with CSS. however it still doesnt resize like the other content page [content page](http://virtual.aissf.net/test/Contact.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing /div argument after sidebar.html

Answer (score 0):

put this script in footer

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $("#wrapper").toggleClass("active");
   });
```

this js file missing modernizr-1.0.min.js

```
<script src="js/modernizr-1.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i took out modernizr ( i dont use it was just testing to see if that fixed it. forgot to delete that line) also i tried moving the script to the footer like on the other one, but didnt work either.)

Comment: <div id="wrapper" class="active"> </div> missing in test page

Comment: code should be lik this <div id="wrapper" class="active"><!-- Sidebar -->
<!-- #Include File="Sidebar.html"-->
 </div>

Comment: fixed the toggle,(THANKS! been trying that for a few days) Text still stays behind that though.

Comment: I did change the css to 2% Left and it moves it over, which does technically work. however, it doesnt auto adjust like on the contact page. any suggestions?

Comment: i cant acces your link.